# How to let the user add a block based on a layout choosen with display suite?

Tags: display-suite

I'm using DS with view_mode_page to display a page of this view mode. E.g. cType House with view_mode "bathroom" is displayed on url:

house/foohousetitle/bathroom.

For this display I choosed a layout 3 colums. Everything is working well.

I want to expand this so that the user can add blocks in the first and second column of this layout. How to do this? If I use the standard drupal blocks it is displayed outside the choosen layout.